# Storing values of individual components of arrays in functions using static

Tags: c++

I had a quick question with regard to arrays in c++.
Let's say that for the program I wanted to store a specific value for each of the individual subscript components of the array. I wanted to create a function to do it and the problem here is I want a way of storing the individual values and remembering it. Since a local variable in a function will get its memory erased, I know we need to employ  a static variable but I don't know how to do it.
Thanks
Varun G.

Let's say I have the function

```
int calculate(int array[], int size)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       array[i]=0;
    }
    if(size >= 0 && size <=9)
    {
        array[size] = array[size]+1;
    }
}
```

Here I want to basically create the array with the 10 numbers all being 0 and then if it falls in the range between 0 and 9 I want to add 1 to the specific position I want to also remember the position and the value so I can repeat it next time
For example if I enter 9 2 times I will get the `array[size]` to be 1 when I want it to be 2

Comment: could you clarify your requirements? Storing a value in a subscript of an array does "remember" it, so I don't understand what your desired function would do other than assign the value to the array cell.

Comment: You mean using references in order to modify an array pointer passed in as a parameter to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int i) {
  static const int data[8] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 };
  return data[i];
} 

int main() {
  std::cout << f(4) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifyinh

Comment: Let's say I have a function

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void init( int a[], size_t n )
{
   std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( 0 ) );

   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) a[i] = std::rand() % n;
}

int main()
{
   const size_t N = 10;
   int a[N];

   init( a, N );

   for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Another way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void init( std::array<int, 10> &a )
{
    a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
}

int main()
{
   std::array<int, 10> a;

   init( a );

   for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If the size of the array has to be changed inside the function then it is better to use class `std::vector` instead of the array

Comment: Let's say I have the function
int calculate(int array[], int size)
{
int i;
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   array[i]=0;
}
if(size >= 0 && size <=9)
{
  array[size]= array[size]+1

}
Here I want to basically create the array with the 10 numbers all being 0 and then if it falls in the range between 0 and 9 I want to add 1 to the specific position I want to also remember the position and the value so I can repeat it next time
For example if I enter 9 2 times I will get the array[size] to be 1 when I want it to be 2

Comment: @Varun Gorantla If you mean to change the size of the array inside the function then it is better to use standard class std::vector

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something along these lines:

```
int calculate( int size )
{
    static int a[10] = { 0 };
    if ( size >= 0 && size < 10 )
    {
        ++a[size];
        return a[size];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The array will only be initialized once and will preserve its values between calls.

Comment: Your a genius truly the next tony stark